# Bitwise operation with difference in order of comparison - (0 to 1) vs (1 to 0)

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, boolean-logic, bitmask

I have a problem in which there are two sets of bits being compared. The first is the initial state, and the second is the new state.

```
Initial State 1010
New State     1100
```

I want to bitwise compare these bitsets and generate a third bitset which represents all bits that went high (0->1) but NOT those that went low (1->0)

```
Desired Result 0100
```

Bits are high which were initially 0 and went to 1. Bits that were high and went low are ignored, so OR and XOR don't seem quite right.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this with bitwise operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words, you are looking for the bits that *are not set* in the initial state and *are set* in the new state. So:

```
LOW2HIGH = ~INITIAL & NEW
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it yeah!